# Appcenter Test pipeline is failing in Appcenter Test task

Tags: testing, azure-devops, cicd, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

Preparing tests... failed. Error: Failed to prepare UI Test artifacts using command "test-cloud.exe prepare" with error message: No tests would run given the current parameters, please try again. If you can't work out how to fix this issue, please contact support.

Tried upgrading Xamarin.UiTest nuget package

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issue on my end and have submitted an issue to app center here:
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2562#issue-1810455671

if you downgrade back to 4.1.4 it fixes the issue.